# Regex - First 6 characters must be digits and be in range (x, y)

Tags: php, regex

I have a little question :)
Need a regex for a string -- 6 characters, for example "112233abc"
This regex should look for first 6 characters to be digits, and be in range 100000-200000 (higher than 100 000 and lower than 200 000)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any question thats 1. 
2. Try this:

```
^[1]\d{5}
```

Or if You want also match 200000:

```
(^[1]\d{5}|^200000)
```

Comment: Yes it is a question. And that regex doesn't work. You can't identify if 112233abc with "^[1]\d{5}" if, first 6 characters are digits and if 112233 is between 100k and 200k. Thanks.

Comment: you want the entire string, an entire row after the 5 digits ?

Comment: @Colar Paul you can work something from Michal M answer... ([1]\d{5}\w*) gets any 6 digits (that begin with 1)  and any word character. If you want to get 6 digits and only text after use something like: ([1]\d{5}[a-zA-Z]*).

Comment: NO there is not :) If you want with letters, here you go: ^[1]\d{5}\w+

Comment: I want my first 6 characters: 112233 to be between 100k and 200k if is possible to be verified with regex code.

Comment: I wrote to You right pattern. Man, i don't get you. https://regex101.com/r/iA7mK1/2